# QLPreviewControllerRepresentation does not conform to protocol UIViewControllerRepresentable

Tags: swift, swift5

Im' new in swift and I want to understand why I got this error from my struct. I want to offer to my customer the possibility to show the file after the download.

Here is my class witch used for :

```html
import SwiftUI
import QuickLook
import FirebaseStorage

struct AdminUsersToPaid: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: AuthViewModel
    @StateObject var adminUserToPaid = AdminUserToPaidModel()
    @State private var soldes: [Solde] = []
    
    @State private var isShowingToast = false
    @State private var toastMessage = ""
    @State private var fileToPreview: URL?
    
    var body: some View {
        content.onAppear{
            Task{
                await adminUserToPaid.fetchSoldeData()
                soldes = adminUserToPaid.soldeList
            }
        }.toast(isShowing: $isShowingToast, text: Text(toastMessage))
            .background(
                QLPreviewControllerRepresentation(fileURL: $fileToPreview)
            )
    }
    
    var content: some View{
        VStack{
            HStack{
                Text("Utilisateur à payer")
                    .font(.system(size: 24).bold())
                Spacer()
                Image(systemName: "eurosign")
                    .font(.system(size: 32))
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
            }.padding()
            Spacer()
            List(soldes){ solde in
                
                HStack{
                    VStack{
                        Text("Nom Complet").font(.system(size: 14)).multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        Text("\(solde.proprietaire)").padding(.top,5).font(.system(size: 12)).foregroundColor(.gray).multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    }
                    Spacer()
                    VStack{
                        Text("Date de la demande").font(.system(size: 14)).multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        Text("\(formatDate(solde.date))").padding(.top,5).font(.system(size: 12)).foregroundColor(.gray).multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    }
                    Spacer()
                    VStack{
                        Text("Etat de la demande").font(.system(size: 14)).multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        Text("\(solde.etat)").padding(.top,5).font(.system(size: 12)).foregroundColor(.gray).multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    }
                    Spacer()
                    VStack{
                        Text("Total du solde").font(.system(size: 14)).multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        Text("\(solde.total)").padding(.top,5).font(.system(size: 12)).foregroundColor(.gray).multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    }
                    Spacer()
                    Button {
                        downloadInvoice(forSolde: solde)
                            } label: {
                                Text("Voir la facture").multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                            }
                }
            }
            NavigationLink {
                AdminDashboard().navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
            } label: {
                HStack(spacing: 3){
                    Text("Retour à la page")
                    Text("Principale").fontWeight(.bold)
                }.font(.system(size: 14))
            }
        }
    }
}

struct QLPreviewControllerRepresentation: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    @Binding var fileURL: URL?
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> some QLPreviewController {
        let controller = QLPreviewController()
        controller.dataSource = context.coordinator
        return controller
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: QLPreviewController, context: Context) {
        uiViewController.reloadData()
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, QLPreviewControllerDataSource {
        let parent: QLPreviewControllerRepresentation

        init(_ parent: QLPreviewControllerRepresentation) {
            self.parent = parent
        }

        func numberOfPreviewItems(in controller: QLPreviewController) -> Int {
            return parent.fileURL != nil ? 1 : 0
        }

        func previewController(_ controller: QLPreviewController, previewItemAt index: Int) -> QLPreviewItem {
            return parent.fileURL! as QLPreviewItem
        }
    }
}

extension AdminUsersToPaid {
    func downloadInvoice(forSolde solde: Solde) {
        let filename = solde.facture
        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("invoices/\(solde.proprietaire)/\(solde.id)/\(filename)")
        
        let localURL = FileManager.default.temporaryDirectory.appendingPathComponent(filename)

        storageRef.write(toFile: localURL) { url, error in
            if let error = error {
                toastMessage = "Erreur lors du téléchargement: \(error.localizedDescription)"
                isShowingToast.toggle()
            } else if let url = url {
                fileToPreview = url
            }
        }
    }
}

private func formatDate(_ date: Date) -> String {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
    return dateFormatter.string(from: date)
}

struct AdminUsersToPaid_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        AdminUsersToPaid()
    }
}
```

Thanks to all for helping. The problem occur on this line to be more explicit but don't know why...

```html
struct QLPreviewControllerRepresentation: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
```

if somebody can explain me what is wrong in this part of the structure I will be thankful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI: Type does not conform to protocol 'UIViewRepresentable' // My Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75176496/swiftui-type-does-not-conform-to-protocol-uiviewrepresentable-my-code)

Comment: witch alias I should use here ?

Comment: QLPreviewController

Comment: doesn't work if I had this typealias too : typealias UIViewControllerType = QLPreviewController. How can I solve the problem ?

Comment: It also not the same protocol used so I think the answer is not the same as this guy...

Comment: Add the the type alias and start typing “make” and “update” you’ll get the right function signatures. There is likely some other little typo the functions have to exact.

Answer (score 0):

```html
import SwiftUI
import QuickLook
import FirebaseStorage

struct AdminUsersToPaid: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: AuthViewModel
    @StateObject var adminUserToPaid = AdminUserToPaidModel()
    @State private var soldes: [Solde] = []
    
    @State private var isShowingToast = false
    @State private var toastMessage = ""
    @State private var fileToPreview: URL?
    
    var body: some View {
        content.onAppear{
            Task{
                await adminUserToPaid.fetchSoldeData()
                soldes = adminUserToPaid.soldeList
            }
        }.toast(isShowing: $isShowingToast, text: Text(toastMessage))
            .background(
                QLPreviewControllerRepresentation(fileURL: $fileToPreview)
            )
    }
    
    var content: some View{
        VStack{
            HStack{
                Text("Utilisateur à payer")
                    .font(.system(size: 24).bold())
                Spacer()
                Image(systemName: "eurosign")
                    .font(.system(size: 32))
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
            }.padding()
            Spacer()
            List(soldes){ solde in
                
                HStack{
                    VStack{
                        Text("Nom Complet").font(.system(size: 14)).multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        Text("\(solde.proprietaire)").padding(.top,5).font(.system(size: 12)).foregroundColor(.gray).multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    }
                    Spacer()
                    VStack{
                        Text("Date de la demande").font(.system(size: 14)).multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        Text("\(formatDate(solde.date))").padding(.top,5).font(.system(size: 12)).foregroundColor(.gray).multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    }
                    Spacer()
                    VStack{
                        Text("Etat de la demande").font(.system(size: 14)).multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        Text("\(solde.etat)").padding(.top,5).font(.system(size: 12)).foregroundColor(.gray).multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    }
                    Spacer()
                    VStack{
                        Text("Total du solde").font(.system(size: 14)).multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        Text("\(solde.total)").padding(.top,5).font(.system(size: 12)).foregroundColor(.gray).multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    }
                    Spacer()
                    Button {
                        downloadInvoice(forSolde: solde)
                            } label: {
                                Text("Voir la facture").multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                            }
                }
            }
            NavigationLink {
                AdminDashboard().navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
            } label: {
                HStack(spacing: 3){
                    Text("Retour à la page")
                    Text("Principale").fontWeight(.bold)
                }.font(.system(size: 14))
            }
        }
    }
}

struct QLPreviewControllerRepresentation: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    typealias UIViewControllerType = QLPreviewController
    @Binding var fileURL: URL?
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> QLPreviewController {
        let controller = QLPreviewController()
        controller.dataSource = context.coordinator
        return controller
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: QLPreviewController, context: Context) {
        uiViewController.reloadData()
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, QLPreviewControllerDataSource{
        let parent: QLPreviewControllerRepresentation
        
        init(_ parent: QLPreviewControllerRepresentation) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        func numberOfPreviewItems(in controller: QLPreviewController) -> Int {
            return parent.fileURL != nil ? 1 : 0
        }
        
        func previewController(_ controller: QLPreviewController, previewItemAt index: Int) -> QLPreviewItem {
            guard let url = parent.fileURL else{
                fatalError("L'url devrait être à jour")
            }
            return url as QLPreviewItem
        }
    }
}


extension AdminUsersToPaid {
    func downloadInvoice(forSolde solde: Solde) {
        let filename = solde.facture
        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("invoices/\(solde.proprietaire)/\(solde.id)/\(filename)")
        
        let localURL = FileManager.default.temporaryDirectory.appendingPathComponent(filename)

        storageRef.write(toFile: localURL) { url, error in
            if let error = error {
                toastMessage = "Erreur lors du téléchargement: \(error.localizedDescription)"
                isShowingToast.toggle()
            } else if let url = url {
                fileToPreview = url
            }
        }
    }
}

private func formatDate(_ date: Date) -> String {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
    return dateFormatter.string(from: date)
}

struct AdminUsersToPaid_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        AdminUsersToPaid()
    }
}
```